# Mediaplayer pause button followed by play, media starts from beginning

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to make a simple media player with play,pause and stop button. Play and stop buttons work fine. However pause button behaves like stop button. When I click play button after pause, it starts from beginning.

```
Button one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mediaButton);
    Button two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mediaButton2);
    Button three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mediaButton3);
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();




    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                return;
            }

            try {
                mp.reset();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                afd = getAssets().openFd("Urge_Surfing.mp3");
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.setLooping(false);
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    });

    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                mp.pause();
            } else {
                return;

            }


        }


    });


    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {

                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();

            } else {
                return;

            }


        }


    });
```

Comment: Because your play button is set to reset the mediaplayer object and that causes the media to start from the beginning. You would have to save the current seek position when you pause the media then seekTo that position before playing again in order to resume.

Comment: What @kabuto178 said, or just don't make play do a full reset.  Also, don't name your buttons 1 2 and 3.  Make them play stop and pause.  It took 4x the time it should have to figure out your code because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the `reset()` call.
According to the [state machine](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), `start()` is the only call required in order to resume from the same place.
Try keeping track of your state and if you are at `PAUSED` state, call only `start()` to resume.
I've used this little [wrapper](https://gist.github.com/2523027) to keep track on current state of the MediaPlayer.

Comment: changed mp.reset() call to mp.start() also added mp.getCurrentPosition() to pause button